# Trying to print "occur = 1" in an if statement but it wont work

Tags: arduino-uno

Cant seem to get this code to work with my arduino, and yes its all hooked up properally, even used leds to show that the button is being pressed, what am i doing wrong or dont know?

```
const int digitalInPin3 = 8;     //switch
int Occur = 0;
int Switch = 0;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
int Switch = digitalRead(digitalInPin3);

if (Switch == 1){
  int Occur = 1;
}


else {
 int occur = 2;
}

   Serial.print("\t Switch =");
   Serial.print(Switch);
   Serial.print("\t occur =");
   Serial.println(Occur);

  delay(1);
}
```

Comment: You have 3 independent `Occur` variables; 1 global, 2 local. You also spell them differently!

Comment: Welcome to Arduino SE.  Be sure to take the tour and earn a badge at https://arduino.stacvkexchange.com/Tour

Answer (score 1):

Remove the *int* from inside the if and else statement. The code would always show 0 because access of *occur*, which is assigned value 1 or 2 is limited to the if..else statement. So the global occur remains 0 always.

So change it to:

```
if (Switch == 1){
 Occur = 1;
}
else {
 Occur = 2;
}
```

This will work.

Comment: The capitalization of the second variable name is incorrect.

Comment: oh, yes. Haven't seen it.

Answer (score 0):

The comments are right, as is the other answer.

Also, I see that both Switch and Occur are highlighted as if they are keywords.

I know for sure Switch is a reserved word.

Take all of these suggestions together.  Remove the int from inside the if.

I recommend you change the variable names entirely to something else.  And make them consistent.

Define them one time at the top then just modify them within the code.